# Using jquery how can I show an element on hover and hide on click

Tags: jquery

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wetVX/1/)

I am trying to do some thing I'd like to think is simple.

animate a partially hidden element on hover, then when i click it, close it.

```
$('#call-to-action').hover(function(){
                $('#call-to-action').animate({
                    right: '0px'                                                    
                }, 1000);
                $('.cta-open').hide();
                $('.cta-close').show();
            });

            $('.cta-close').click(function(){
                $('#call-to-action').animate({
                    right: '-364px'                                                 
                }, 1000);
                $('.cta-close').hide();
                $('.cta-open').show();
                stop();

            });
```

the fiddle has the code I am using  as well as the elements.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.hover()` to `.mouseenter()`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wetVX/2/)**

Since you're only passing a single function to hover, it gets executed when the mouse enters OR leaves the element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#call-to-action').mouseenter(function () {
        $('#call-to-action').animate({
            right: '0px'
        }, 1000);
        $('.cta-open').hide();
        $('.cta-close').show();
    });
    $('.cta-close').click(function () {
        $('#call-to-action').animate({
            right: '-364px'
        }, 1000);
        $('.cta-close').hide();
        $('.cta-open').show();
        stop();
    });
});
```